# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
create FUNCTION GetProductPercity(@CityName nvarchar(50))
RETURNS @returntable TABLE 
(
    [productName] nvarchar(50),
    [Quantity] int
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @title nvarchar(50)
    declare @quantity int

    IF( @cityName in (select s.City from Suppliers s) )
    BEGIN
        set @title = (
            select  p.ProductName 
            from Suppliers s  right join Products p 
                 on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
            where s.City = @CityName
        )

        set @quantity = (
            select  count(p.ProductID)
            from Suppliers s  right join Products p 
                 on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
            where s.City = @CityName
        )

        insert into @returntable([productName],[Quantity])
        values(@title,@quantity)
    END
    --INSERT @returntable
    --SELECT @CityName, @param2
    RETURN
END
```

```sql
select * from dbo.GetProductPercity('london')
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 126
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Please put your code in markdown formatting as follows:
```
// all your code
```

Comment: Also, please provide some more detail about your question, including the *full* error message as well as what result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why are you using a RIGHT JOIN here? Your where predicate turns it into an inner join anyway. And a table valued function should be a single statement or it is going to suffer performance problems like crazy. This really can and should be a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could greatly simplify this by turning this into an inline table valued function. Not only will it resolve your error, you will have better performance and type a lot less code. I just don't really understand the point of your original RIGHT join. I would assume by the name that you want the count of suppliers for the given city. Turn this around so Products is the main table. And change your join to an inner join.

```
create FUNCTION GetProductPercity
(
    @CityName nvarchar(50)
)RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
    select p.ProductName
        , Quantity = count(*)
    from Products p
    join Suppliers s on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
    where s.City = @CityName
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
create FUNCTION GetProductPercity 
(
   @CityName nvarchar(50) 
) 
RETURNS @returntable TABLE 
( [productName] nvarchar(50), [Quantity] int ) 
AS
BEGIN 

INSERT into @returntable([productName],[Quantity]) 
SELECT p.ProductName , count(p.ProductID) 
 FROM Suppliers s 
 inner join Products p on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID 
 WHERE s.City = @CityName
 return
END
```

Comment: I appreciate it that is correct but change inner join to right join